# Calling Clients.Others.SendAsync disconnects recipient

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

To test my app, I open multiple connections to a signalr hub running on localhost in my browser. They connect fine up until one client calls the *Host* function at which point the other clients throw an error:

> [2020-04-23T18:17:18.374Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
>   Utils.ts:178 [2020-04-23T18:17:18.511Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().) called while in state Connected.
>
> Utils.ts:168 [2020-04-23T18:17:18.511Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().'.
>
> Utils.ts:178 [2020-04-23T18:17:18.512Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().) called while in state Connected.

Here's the function on the server side

```cs
        public async Task Host(string lobbyId)
        {
            //generate _lobbies here...
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveLobbies", 
                new { lobbies = new Lobby[] { _lobbies } })
        }
```

client side function "ReceiveLobbies" doesn't get called since the connection is closed. I have done a quick test and know that I can have multiple clients on localhost so why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my Lobby object contains a list of Player objects that each have their own Lobby property, ergo an infinite recursion during serialization

You can try to install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson) NuGet package to switch to Newtonsoft.Json, then you can make it ignore circular references rather than throw an exception by set ReferenceLoopHandling setting, like below.

```
services.AddSignalR().AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(opt=> {
    opt.PayloadSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fei, I've also looked into the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute but I'll keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the signalr app I realized I was getting a json serialization error because the depth of the lobby variable exceeds limits for the now obvious reason that my Lobby object contains a list of Player objects that each have their own Lobby property, ergo an infinite recursion during serialization